# Do I need Redux if using Realm?

Tags: react-native, redux, realm

If we are using Realm in a React-Native app (with ~ 30 different 'screens') and have (Realm) change event listeners setup on the apps components (eg a ListView) - what benefit if any, do we gain from also using Redux in this app ?

Comment: Redux is an architecture, it's orthogonal to Realm

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped. Then, I read this excellent detailed article from a Swift developer. Now I can really see the app (state) organisational benefits of Redux. https://realm.io/news/benji-encz-unidirectional-data-flow-swift/